# While using Python's msilib- UPDATE statement fails with error 2259

Tags: python, windows-installer, python-2.6

I have the following class method that is meant to run database statements:

```
class CDatabaseModifier(object):
    def __init__(self, database):
        """ Constructor gets database
        """
        self._database = database
    def RunStatement(self, statement):
        """ Runs statement on database 
        """ 
        view = self._database.OpenView(statement)
        view.Execute(None)
        view.Close()
        self._database.Commit()
```

This works with `INSERT INTO` and `DELETE` statements, but for some reason I keep getting `MSIError 2259` exceptions when I try to run the `UPDATE` statement with **string** as the parameter of `SET`. For example:

```
import msilib
db = msilib.OpenDatabase(r'C:\some\path\to\msi\bar.msi', msilib.MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT)
m = CDatabaseModifier(db)
m.RunStatement("UPDATE AppId SET ActivateAtStorage = 66 WHERE AppId = 'aaa'") # works OK
m.RunStatement("UPDATE AppId SET AppId = 'ccc' WHERE AppId = 'bbb'") # throws MSIError: 1: 2259 2
m.RunStatement("INSERT INTO AppId (AppId, RemoteServerName) VALUES ('foo', 'bar')") # works OK
```

More info: 
In the `AppId` table `ActivateAtStorage` column is `short` type, `AppId` and `RemoteServerName` columns are `string` type.

It says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the 2259 error means that

> Database: [2] Table(s) Update failed. Queries must adhere to the restricted Windows Installer SQL syntax.

Because the syntax of the UPDATE statement seams right, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is magic: The minute you post a question you suddenly get the answer.

Anyway, I missed the part from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that clearly states that

> UPDATE queries **only work on nonprimary key columns**.

which was exactly what I was trying to do (`AppId` is a primary key column). It had nothing to do with **string** types after all.